# Kendo Angular button overflow tabindex accessibility problem

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, accessibility, kendo-ui-angular2, tabindex

I am using Kendo-toolbar with these configurations:

```
<kendo-toolbar [overflow]="true" [popupSettings]="popupSettings">
```

while popupSettings are:

```
popupSettings = {
    appendTo: viewContainerRef,
    animate: false,
    width: 192
};
```

Whenever I resize my page and the overflow button appear, it is inaccessible with keyboard tabs.
The main toolbar component has `tabindex="0"`, and the overflow button has `tabindex="-1"`, but as soon as I try to reach it with keyboard tabs the toolbar's tabindex changes to -1 and the overflow button tabindex stays -1.

Is it a known issue with Kendo-toolbar? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating the `kendo-angular-toolbar` from `4.1.1` to `4.1.3`